# Windows 10 shows Ipv4 Adress as 192.168.... while internet ip lookup shows difrent ipv4

Tags: ipv6, ipv4

My issue is that Windows is indicating my PC is being assigned a local intranet IPv4 address while `WhatsMyIP` shows another IPv4 address and even a wrong location.

[image]

I know my windows is remotely monitored and how do I remove this? I'm having a lot of issues also because of it like windows is shutting down every now and then and GPU ramps up to 100% fan speed (Bitcoin Mining enabler Virus?) I can still chat with others but my screens are in standby and I have to press the power button and restart manually to fix it.

Applications not loading up properly and just closing on start which I fix by updating my bios then the applications work properly which is because my pc is remotely monitored and someone is just bricking my application to annoy me.

GPU: AMD Vega 64 (dusted out and repasted) temps @ full load never over 75°
CPU: AMD Ryzen 2600X temps normal at about 60°
PSU: new 850W

I changed provider and for around 3 days I had my standard IPv4 address but then it changed to this local pc.  This is a home pc no work pc.

Comment: Why do you believe your PC is being remotely monitored.  The information you provide does not provide any indication.  The fact you have intranet IPv4 address assigned to your PC is perfectly normal.  You must explain the reason you believe you are monitored, be specific, do not provide this additional information in a comment.  You need to edit your question.  Please be careful of the typographical mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you put a strong, secured router with your ISP input to the router.

Then hook your computer to an internal LAN port on the router.

This should stop people from accessing your machine.

I am not sure, if people have been accessing your machine and causing issues, that you can fix by scanning for viruses.  You may need to back up and rebuild the machine.